# Transforming grouped income data into continuous distribution

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, fitting

I have data with income information provided in grouped, income ranges.

However, for my research purpose, I want to estimate a continuous distribution, in other words from the shares of each income-range, I then want to derive a possible underlying continuous distribution. For this purpose, I was thinking to fit a generalized beta distribution (a Singh-Maddala one) and then using the estimated parameters to generate a random income continuous variable. However, I do not exactly know how to implement this approach in R.

Suppose I have the following:

```
structure(list(PR_SUELDO = structure(c("3", "3", "3", "2", "3", 
"3", "1", "2", "1", "4", "2", "1", "4", "1", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "9", "3", "9", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "4", 
"3", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1"), format.stata = "%2s")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

where 1 to 8 are the income range categories (1 is 0-699, 2: 700-999, 3: 1000-1499, 4: 1500-1999, 5: 2000-2499, 6: 2500-2999, 7: 3000+). I know about the GB2group package and the fitgroup.sm function, but how shall I proceed to fit and generate the underlying continuous variable?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You have five distinct values $1,2,3,4,9$ (and a missing one).  How do you think this translates to income?

Comment: Provided you specify the endpoints of each income range, you have *binned interval-valued* data.  A general method to fit a distribution to such data (and check its goodness of fit) is described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56015.  But since no such endpoint information is evident in this post, there's no way to proceed.

Comment: see McDonald (1988), or Von Hippel et al., (2017). Without top endpoints there are 2 ways: fitting a generalized beta, or bounded midpoint estimator, which obtain the pseudo-mid point assuming a Pareto distribution for the top-end.

Comment: There is a widely used heuristic in applied analysis to convert these values to a nondiscrete distribution. Find the midpoints of the ranged buckets and the first number of the end bucket and reassign the integers with these values. Far from perfect but as an approximation, it works.

Comment: @Mike On the contrary, that can't even be applied in this instance due to the last *unbounded* interval; and the varying widths of the intervals indicate the result might be less than satisfactory.  If you think I am incorrect in this assessment, then please post an answer demonstrating the efficacy of your recommendation.

Comment: @whuber I provided two references - in particular McDonald (1988) is the most relevant in the literature - who indeed use an example with different intervals widths and not-bounded top-end.

Comment: That method is not at all like the one recommended by Mike Hunter.  The link I gave in my initial comment *fully* answers your question.  I strongly suspect it to be the same as or similar to the one in McDonald.

Comment: Indeed there are 2 possible ways: 1. using midpoints (Von Himpel et al., 2017), using different assumptions when top-end is not bounded - a more sophisticated approach of one suggested by @MikeHunter  and 2. Using generalized beta. The provided question falls into this case, as it is exactly the same as the example in footnote 6 of McDonald: I have different widths for the income-brackets, and the top-end is not bounded.

Comment: As noted, the suggestion is a widely used heuristic, an imperfect workaround in applied analysis, not a theoretically demonstrable, much less provable claim. It has no ground truth other than its utility, just another rule of thumb of which there are many in statistics. It's worth noting that, at least since Pareto, it's known that actual income and wealth distributions are extreme valued with tails fatter than exponential. Given that and regarding upper unboundedness, this heuristic is directionally conservative, while consistent with all other survey-based responses to income queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many people fall into each income bracket (and what the boundaries of the brackets are) and you have some distribution for the population distribution of income you want to assume, you could treat this as interval censored data (i.e. if there's 200 people in the 0-699 bracket, you have 200 records with income interval censored to lie in (0, 699)).

Comment: I was thinking to use income as outcome, in the way you suggest doesn't mean to use counts (e.g. 200 people) as outcome? which could be a solution in a different perspective, thanks.